# Esper: Reset std:firstevent()

Tags: stock, esper

Currently i am using following piece of code. It looks for the first event of ValueTrigger and saves it and ignore all the next ValueTriggered Events. Then it compares currentData.last
value with first ValueTriggered event.

```
select
*
from
Tick as currentData unidirectional,
ValueTriggered.std:firstevent() as triggerPoint
where
currentData.last < triggerPoint.highValue;
```

What i want to achieve is to rest the value of triggerPoint when ever the condition is matched. I want to change std:firstevent() with some function which reset value when ever "where" condition matches(by reset i mean next ValueTriggerd Value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like "every ValueTriggered -> Tick(...)"
A "reset" can also be done using explicit delete from a named window.